# Fail to install MongooseIM In Mac OS

Tags: ios, git, macos, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am going to develop a chat application with MongooseIM Server, but fail to install MongooseIM sever setup on my local pc, Can any one please help me to fix this error, Thanks in advance.

Following : http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.1/user-guide/Getting-started/

error : 
===> Failed to fetch and copy dep:{git,"git://github.com/goj/base16.git"{ref,                                  "f78918e7b593fbdc35ec9bcc349aa50f47f45a8b[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see those dependences are expressed using the [`git://` protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol).

Try instead using the https one:

```
 git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

And see if the same process still fails.
Make sure you are using a recent version of git (what `git --version` returns?)

Comment: Thanks for replying. it worked for me but now getting below error. please help.

===> Compiling _build/default/lib/pooler/src/pooler_starter.erl failed
_build/default/lib/pooler/src/pooler_starter.erl:34: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

Comment: @Bucket Could you make a new question with the text of that compilation error? That would allow me or other to focus on that new issue.

Comment: getting same error now, which i have asked in my question. and my git version is "git version 2.14.1"

Comment: @Bucket the "Failed to fetch and copy dep:{git,"git://github.com"? That should be resolved with `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Comment: Already try to change into rebar.congif file with below line
"https://github.com/goj/base16.git"

Comment: @Bucket Don't try and change existing file: the config allows git to transparently use https when it sees git. That allows you to *not* change any file.

Comment: you means to say no need to make change any where in directory ?

Comment: @Bucket Yes: you only have to set the Git config as explained in the answer.

Comment: i have try to paste below line int my terminal but still same error
git config --global url."https://github.com/goj/base16.git"